How does amplitude amplification work (in Grover's Algorithm) and does this code for it work?
I understand amplitude amplification at a high level: operations and gates are applied to the qubits such that the solution states amplitude is raised while the non-solution states are lowered. However, how is this done in code? I was told that this is a correct implementation (but could somone tell me why?):
def diffusion_operator(qc, n):
    qc.h([0,n-1])
    qc.z([0,n-1])
    qc.cz(0,n-1)
    qc.h([0,n-1])

